# read xml file with namespace and load_file in xml

Tags: php, xml, parsing

I'm trying to read xml file by using xml_loadfile.
The xml file contains namespace and i can read it with xmlload_string, but when i use loadfile it doesn't work.
XML is stored on my server.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <exp:Input xmlns:exp="http://xps.com">
            <exp:serviceId>namesurname</exp:serviceId>
            <exp:data>
                <exp:xml>coded</exp:xml>
              
            </exp:data>
        </exp:Input>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

i tried with

```
    <?php
    $xmlFilePath = 'xml/2.xml';
    
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($xmlFilePath);
    
    $namespaces = $xml->getNamespaces(true);
    
    $exp = $xml->children($namespaces['exp']);
    
    $serviceId = $exp->Input->serviceId;
    
    echo $serviceId;
    ?>
```

but nothing is displayed on screen

I need to read the child called serviceId

Comment: Is that the complete error message you got? Please always copy the complete message, so we don't have to guess what it is.

Comment: You haven't shared the full text of the error, but I'm guessing that the call to simplexml_load_file returned `false`.  I suggest this could either be because the file couldn't be opened, or there is an error in the XML.  As you've been able to load it as a string, this sounds like a file path or file permissions problem.  What do the error logs tell you?

Comment: @Rob Eyre i updated the xml

Comment: @KIKO Software updated.

Comment: OK, well the assumption of Rob Eyre is correct: `simplexml_load_file($xmlFilePath);` returned `false`. Switch on error reporting or check the error logs.

Comment: @KIKO Software but the file is on the server and i can see it... so the path is correct... have a look now at the updated xml code

Comment: ops, now i don't see any errors... but also i don't see nothing on screen...so it seems that the child is not called... can we start from there?

Comment: It's not a good idea to change your question like this, after an hour. Anyway, now you need to debug your code. For example like this: https://3v4l.org/DOYV4 Notice how `$xml->children($namespaces['exp']);` does return an empty object?

Comment: thanks @KIKOSoftware and sorry for confusion.
The problem is that i'm not able to read the serviceID content... I saw that you can read exp namespace... but how to point to serviceid?

Comment: ok i see that nobody knows how to do. :( Maybe it's impossibile...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Challenge accepted. No, but you're right, I wasn't able to do it without a slight fiddle:

```
$xmlFilePath = 'xml/2.xml';
$content = file_get_contents($xmlFilePath);
$content = str_replace(['soapenv:', 'exp:'], '', $content);
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($content);
$serviceId = $xml->Body->Input->serviceId;
echo $serviceId;
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/aqquM

By replacing `soapenv:` and `exp:` with nothing, I can handle the input as normal XML without worrying about namespaces.

There is however as real [SoapClient()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient) in PHP, but I haven't tried that because I have a suspicious that I don't have all the information I need about your SOAP response.

Comment: Thanks works perfectly!

Comment: @marco If it works so well at least you could upvote the answer, and also Accept it as way of thanking the person that assisted you